# TypeScript function param and return type

Tags: typescript

```
type TreeNode = {
  value: number;
  left: TreeNode | null;
  right: TreeNode | null;
};

function minNode(node: TreeNode | null): number | null {
  if (node === null) {
    return null;
  }
  return node.value;
}

const node: TreeNode = {
  value: 1,
  left: null,
  right: null,
};
const a = minNode(node)!;
```

In this function, when I pass `TreeNode` it returns `number`, when I pass `null` it returns `null`.
How to modify this function so I can get rid of this `!` when `node` is not null?

Comment: But what will the function return when `node.right` is actually `null`? You could throw an error, or return a default number value (e.g. `0`).

Comment: You can't, because the compiler doesn't (usually) know at compile time whether the argument is `null` or not, so it cannot infer whether the return value is `null` or not either. Nothing wrong with using a `!` if you have more knowledge than the compiler does at the call site.

Comment: Or else you'll need another `if` statement... `if(node.right) newValue = ...`

Comment: I just edit it , in this case ```!``` is still needed

Comment: please share reproducible example

Comment: code is updated, if I remove ```!```, a will be ```number | null```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an overload:

```js
function minNode(node:  null): null;
function minNode(node: TreeNode): number;
function minNode(node: TreeNode | null): number | null {
  if (node === null) {
    return null;
  }
  return node.value;
}
```

Comment: wait, if node is ```TreeNode | null```, I have to add one more ```function minNode(node: TreeNode | null): number | null;``` , that looks wierd.

Comment: @Johan i don't understand your question.

Comment: I tried this ```const n: any = null;
const node: TreeNode | null = n;
const a = minNode(node);```

Comment: I still don't know what you're asking, but if you want types to work correctly you don't use `any`.

Comment: I mean ```node: TreeNode | null``` can't pass to your version of ```minNode``` function, sorry for my poor English expresion.

Comment: ```function minNode(node:  null): null;
function minNode(node: TreeNode): number;
function minNode(node: TreeNode | null): number | null;
function minNode(node: TreeNode | null): number | null {}``` I have to do this

Comment: can you narrow before calling the function?

Comment: Yes, I can. I just want to learn the right way to write this kind of functions.